# Change Brightness and Contrast for an IP Camera through window store apps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, ip-camera

I want to change the contrast and brightness of the IP camera through my window 8.1 app UI.

Whatever post i saw are only for webcams, as there are very less information about this.

i have gone through [here](http://www.prodigyproductionsllc.com/articles/automation/insteon-wireless-security-ip-camera-c-controller/) application but it does not connect to my IP Camera.

My App looks like :-

[image]

Comment: Did you set the network capability on your app?

Comment: Yeap it's working fine when not using the application and also i given IP address ,port number, user credentials and everything right

Comment: That application is a winform one so there is no app manifest to set the network capability i only choose that app to check the functionality.

Comment: Any API'S of RTSP which can change the properties of the IPCAM

Comment: I'm confused. Does it work in win forms and not wpf?  Either way, you will get more help if you post an example of the code you have tried.

Comment: You're right ..i am working on the code i will post the working code very soon